# How to display error msg if the value of id text field is not in form?

Tags: php, mysqli

code:

```
if(isset($_POST["add"]))
{
extract($_POST);

$facilities = $_POST['facilities'];
$chk=""; 

foreach($facilities as $chk1)  
 {  
    $chk .= $chk1.",";  
 } 

$exam = $_POST['exam'];
$chks=""; 

foreach($exam as $chked)  
 {  
    $chks .= $chked.",";  
 } 

  $filename = $_FILES['college_image']['name'];
  $path = "college_banner/";
  $move=move_uploaded_file($_FILES['college_image']['tmp_name'],$path.$_FILES['college_image']['name']);

  $filename2 = $_FILES['logo']['name'];
  $path2 = "college_logo/";
  $move=move_uploaded_file($_FILES['logo']['tmp_name'],$path2.$_FILES['logo']['name']);

 echo "insert into all_colleges(college_name,establish,approve,affiliated,address,website,about_us,city,courses,logo,college_image,phone,field,tag,video1,video2,facilities,courses_fee,short_name,state,exams,form_fee,college_commission,client_commission,form_type)values('$name','$establish','$approve','$affiliated','$address','$website','$about_us','$city','$course','$filename2','$filename','$phone2','$field','$tag','$video1','$video2','$chk','$fee','$short','$state','$chks','$form_fee','$college_commission','$client_commission','$form_type')";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql2);
if($result == true)
{
  $msg .= "<h5 style='color:green;'>Successfull</h5>";
}
else
{
  $msg .= "<h5 style='color:red;'>Error</h5>";
}
}
```

In database I have an auto_increment id i.e. college_id but when I remove auto_increment over college_id then it show successfull message when click on add button instead of error. So, how can I fix this problem ?

Thank You

Comment: Use [mysqli_affected_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php). It return the number of rows affected by the last INSERT query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter with you `college_id` just make sure if it is `AUTO_INCREMENT` then it must be `PRIMARY KEY`.

And in SQL query you are not assigning query to your `$sql2` variable so use

```
echo $sql2 = "insert into all_colleges ...";
//---^ assign query in $sql2
$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql2); // <-- you are passing $sql2
```

1 more thing you can use [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) without using loops for checked values in a single statement like,

```
$chk= = implode(',',$_POST['facilities']);
```